# SQL Row_Count function with Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a query that returns a set of results as a table called `DATA`, from several `UNION ALL` joined queries.

I am then doing `ROW_NUMBER()` on this, to get the row number for a specific grouping (WorksOrderNo)

```
ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition by Data.WorksOrderNo order by Data.WorksOrderNo) as RowNo,
```

Is there an equivalent `ROW_Count` function where I can specify a partition, and return the count of rows for that partition?

```
ROW_Count() Over(partition by Data.WorksOrderNo order by Data.WorksOrderNo) as RowNo ???
```

Reason being, this is query being used to drive a report layout. 
As part of this, I need to format based on whether the total row count for each WorksOrderNo is >1 or not.

So for instance if there were three rows for a works order, the `row_number` function currently returns 1, 2 and 3, where the row count would return 3 on each row.

Comment: Pretty sure COUNT(*) does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function is simply `COUNT()`.  In SQL Server, all the aggregation functions can be used as window functions, as long as they do not use `DISTINCT`.

Note that for the total count, you do not want the `ORDER BY`:

```
COUNT(*) Over (partition by Data.WorksOrderNo) as cnt
```

If you include the `ORDER BY`, then the `COUNT()` is cumulative, rather than constant for all rows in the partition.

Comment: Perfect. I knew there would be a simple way of doing it using count. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need `group by` and `count`:

```
select WorksOrderNo, count(*) as Row_Count
from Data 
group by WorksOrderNo
```

Comment: I cannot group by due to the select containing other unique rows.

Comment: @OWSam well, technically you can place this query into CTE and join back... but solution suggested by Gordon is much more elegant.